# Why data from InnerHTML changes / is not available via beautifulsoup?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape the wave height of https://waterberichtgeving.rws.nl/wbviewer/maak_grafiek.php?loc=HAEW2&set=golf_spectra&nummer=1&format=wbcharts

My issue is that if i use beautifulsoup or selenium, the actual height is changed to a - and i only print
Hs

- cm
  TM02
- sec
  Hmax
- cm
  Hm0
- cm
  Hs7
- cm

The element is: `<div class="dataTableCell"><span data-key="hs">**122**</span> cm</div>`
the bold part is what I am trying to get, however if I print innerHTML i get: `<div class="dataTableCell"><span data-key="hs">**-**</span> cm</div>`
?
now i cant retrieve this data. Anyone knows how i can go around this issue?

```
url = "https://waterberichtgeving.rws.nl/wbviewer/maak_grafiek.php?loc=HAEW2&set=golf_spectra&nummer=1&format=wbcharts"

response = requests.get(url)

if response.status_code == 200:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

    # Find all elements with the class "dataTableCell"
    data_cells = soup.find_all("div", class_="dataTableCell")

    # Extract and print the inner text from each element
    for data_cell in data_cells:
        inner_text = data_cell.get_text()
        print(inner_text)
else:
    print("Failed to retrieve the web page. Status code:", response.status_code)
```

Answer (score 3):

The data is obtained dynamically via javascript when rendered by the browser and is not available to `requests` in the static response, which is why `BeautifulSoup` cannot find it.

Based on @Andrej's approach of using the API, which in my eyes is completely correct, additively focus on the desired part of the data. Adjust the parameters of the request accordingly to the metadata and transfer them according to the logic in the `javascript` (you can see in the page source):

```
if (spectrametavalues) {
                        var spectraMetaData = {};
                        spectraMetaData.hs = spectrametavalues[i][0];
                        spectraMetaData.hmax = spectrametavalues[i][4];
                        spectraMetaData.hs7 = spectrametavalues[i][15];
                        spectraMetaData.tm02 = spectrametavalues[i][6] / 10;
                        spectraMetaData.hm0 = spectrametavalues[i][16];
                        spectraMetaData.e10 = spectrametavalues[i][19];
                        allSpectraMeta.push(spectraMetaData);
                    }
```

##### Example

*Be aware that this focus a single day only and you have adjust it to you needs:*

```
import requests

api_url = 'https://waterberichtgeving.rws.nl/wbviewer/wb_api.php'

params = {
    'request': 'spectra',
    'spectra_meta': 'GD_S_1.1-20',
    'loc': 'HAEW2',
    'start': '2023-10-04T00:00:00Z',
    'end': '2023-10-04T00:00:00Z',
}

json_data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()

meta = json_data.get('spectra_meta').get('values')[0]

meta_data = {
    'hs' : meta[0],
    'hmax' : meta[4],
    'hs7' : meta[15],
    'tm02' : meta[6]/10,
    'hm0' : meta[16],
    'e10' : meta[19]
}
```

##### Output

```
{'hs': 285, 'hmax': 444, 'hs7': 202, 'tm02': 5.8, 'hm0': 304, 'e10': 71}
```

Comment: Yes, I was too lazy to search where the computation is done in JavaScript :) +1

Answer (score 2):

The graph values are loaded from different URL using Ajax. Here is an example how to load it using `requests` to pandas dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

api_url = "https://waterberichtgeving.rws.nl/wbviewer/wb_api.php"

params = {
    "request": "spectra",
    "polar": "GR_S_1.1-102",
    "spectra": "GD_S_1.28-78",
    "spectra_meta": "GD_S_1.1-20",
    "loc": "HAEW2",
    "start": "2023-09-27T11:10:00Z",
    "end": "2023-10-04T11:10:00Z",
}

data = requests.get(api_url, params=params).json()

df = pd.DataFrame(data["spectra"]["values"], columns=None)
df["time"] = pd.to_datetime(data["spectra"]["times"], unit="s")

print(df.head())
```

Prints:

```
     0    1    2     3     4     5      6      7      8      9     10     11     12     13      14      15       16       17       18      19      20      21      22      23      24      25      26      27      28      29      30      31     32      33      34     35     36     37     38     39     40     41     42     43     44     45     46     47     48     49     50                time
0  0.0  3.0  9.0  29.0  35.0  34.0   82.0  211.0  373.0  678.0  631.0  668.0  504.0  775.0  2512.0  5187.0   8901.0  13305.0  10361.0  8137.0  7099.0  3880.0  2746.0  3324.0  1912.0  1637.0   835.0  1411.0   912.0  1053.0   922.0   931.0  446.0   542.0   587.0  465.0  430.0  360.0  337.0  179.0  194.0  189.0  178.0  198.0  187.0  161.0  275.0  141.0  204.0  192.0  173.0 2023-09-27 11:30:00
1  0.0  0.0  1.0   8.0  23.0  24.0   80.0  362.0  693.0  722.0  492.0  375.0  461.0  711.0  2456.0  5405.0   7100.0  10766.0   5673.0  4649.0  5201.0  2599.0  3621.0  2030.0  1299.0  1978.0  1519.0   999.0   980.0  1073.0  1228.0  1193.0  504.0   531.0   843.0  830.0  709.0  337.0  433.0  228.0  315.0  245.0  269.0  325.0  291.0  231.0  260.0  185.0  188.0  124.0  167.0 2023-09-27 12:00:00
2  0.0  1.0  1.0   7.0  25.0  31.0   82.0  268.0  429.0  674.0  339.0  488.0  418.0  427.0  1288.0  5666.0   6914.0   6834.0   6760.0  7404.0  4089.0  5000.0  3248.0  3019.0  1535.0  1037.0  1152.0   782.0   977.0   900.0   758.0   921.0  628.0   571.0   475.0  952.0  500.0  401.0  442.0  344.0  383.0  442.0  242.0  304.0  313.0  199.0  149.0  162.0  158.0  136.0  213.0 2023-09-27 12:30:00
3  0.0  0.0  1.0   5.0  16.0  31.0  102.0  343.0  580.0  360.0  371.0  391.0  389.0  541.0  2002.0  6538.0  12996.0   8854.0   6761.0  7255.0  6366.0  3946.0  2684.0  2995.0  1885.0  2370.0  2003.0  1384.0   895.0  1266.0   834.0  1166.0  745.0   745.0   610.0  689.0  583.0  611.0  571.0  610.0  411.0  276.0  389.0  361.0  376.0  233.0  324.0  236.0  186.0  178.0  194.0 2023-09-27 13:00:00
4  0.0  0.0  1.0  10.0  28.0  34.0   96.0  334.0  340.0  641.0  513.0  555.0  411.0  644.0  1373.0  4424.0   9215.0   9234.0   8767.0  7881.0  6419.0  2098.0  2423.0  2686.0  1820.0  2022.0  2031.0  1219.0  1027.0  1351.0  1420.0  1585.0  845.0  1229.0  1205.0  939.0  877.0  812.0  766.0  617.0  735.0  473.0  298.0  264.0  383.0  239.0  430.0  186.0  159.0  232.0  148.0 2023-09-27 13:30:00
```